# Marvell 9230 - RAID 10 3 disks suddenly appear as unconfigured

Tags: hardware-raid, data-recovery, raid10

I was rebooting my NAS running Open Media Vault, and noticed that the RAID controller (Marvell 9230) reported degraded RAID operation since one disk wasn't found. 
I shut down the box to investigate.

I figured out that the first drive accidentally was moved out of its SATA port during a move of the NAS. I put it back in place and booted the server once again. Now it does indeed find the drive again, which is good.

However, the RAID config is now offline, and the 3 drives that were in operation a couple of minutes ago are now listed as free unconfigured drives, and the only drive left in the configured state is the drive that was just put back in. I have very limited options but to recreate the virtual disk, but as that would erase all data, I'm not really into doing that since nothing is wrong with the disks. I'm pretty sure the configuration is still on the disks, but for some reason the Marvell controller simply doesn't recognize it.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any way I can force the configuration into being recognized again, and if not, will I be able to recover files from the disks?

The setup is 4x 5 tb disks in RAID 10 (striping and mirroring)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, this question may only be answered by the mainboard manual/chipset documentation.

What I assume that happend is the following:
Disk1 got disconnected, but the raid keept working as it could tolerate the failure of one disk.
Then you re-connected Disk1, and the system reads the Disk now at first.
The 'Update Time' / 'Event Count' does not match the other disks, but for some reason the firmware does not figure out that the other disks should all be fine.

You could try to remove disk one, and if the raid is then recognized and working with the other 3 disks, you'd be lucky and could wipe the disk1 and re-sync it.

Under any circumstance the first thing to do is taking full backups of all four disks with dd or ddrescue. Any writing operation to the disks in that situation can make the already happened damage even worse.

What I'm not really understanding in your setup is the use of the raid controllers firmware raid feature. As you are running OpenMediavault I personally would recommend using mdadm raid, this would be hardware independant and more flexible, especially when it comes to rescuing failed states.